# Create new MySql user with same grants as existing user

Tags: mysql, mariadb

To create a new user usr_B with same grants as an existing user usr_A we can always `SHOW GRANTS` for usr_A and then `GRANT` those privileges to usr_B, but is there a built-in command for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than copying the grants over, consider creating a "role" with suitable privileges.  Then `GRANT` a role `TO` a user.

MySQL:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-role.html

MariaDB:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-role/